# changecurrentdirectorypath changes the current path to null in objective c

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, finder

I have tried many times to change current directory to `/User/{username}`
so I can create new folder at `/User/{username}/` directory.
The code i've used is:

```
filemgr = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

currentpath = [filemgr currentDirectoryPath];

NSLog (@"from changing directory Current directory is %@", currentpath);

if ([filemgr changeCurrentDirectoryPath: @"/Users/"] == NO)
    NSLog (@"from changing directory Cannot change directory.");
else
    NSLog(@"directory changed is %@",currentpath);

currentpath = [filemgr currentDirectoryPath];

NSLog (@"directory after changed Current directory is %@", currentpath);
```

and gets the output like:

> 2015-12-05 11:47:43.450 test2_Finder[970:33618] from changing directory Current directory is /Users/macbookpro/Library/Containers/com.eebs.Test2.test2-Finder/Data
>   2015-12-05 11:47:43.450 test2_Finder
>
> [970:33618] directory changed is /Users/macbookpro/Library/Containers/com.eebs.Test2.test2-Finder/Data
>   2015-12-05 11:47:43.458 test2_Finder[970:33618] directory after changed Current directory is **(null)**
>
> 2015-12-05 11:47:43.458 test2_Finder[970:33618] -[FinderSync init] launched from /Users/macbookpro/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Test2-hbxwqkjtnzaewlcisyxybyfbzefb/Build/Products/Debug/Test2.app/Contents/PlugIns/test2_Finder.appex ; compiled at 11:47:39

Comment: What is the thing that you call current directory?  What do you mean by changing current directory?

Comment: Thanx EITomato right now when i use
'BOOL isDir;
    NSFileManager *fileManager= [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    if(![fileManager fileExistsAtPath:@"../Library/Java/folder1" isDirectory:&isDir])
        if(![fileManager createDirectoryAtPath:@"../Library/Java/folder1" withIntermediateDirectories:YES attributes:nil error:NULL])
            NSLog(@"Error: Create folder failed %@",@"/Library/Java/");'             creates a folder in /Users/macbookpro/Library/Containers/com.eebs.Test2.test2-Finder/Data/file:/Library/Java folder what i want is to create a folder in /User/macbookpro/java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Finally got the solution for creating folders to user directory* such as 
"/Users/macbookpro/folder"
`NSString *userPath=[NSOpenStepRootDirectory() stringByAppendingString:@"Users/"];
    NSString *userPath1=[userPath stringByAppendingString:NSUserName()];
    NSString *userPath2=[userPath1 stringByAppendingString:@"/folder/"];
    if(![fileManager fileExistsAtPath:userPath2 isDirectory:&isDir])
        if(![fileManager createDirectoryAtPath:userPath2 withIntermediateDirectories:YES attributes:nil error:NULL])
            NSLog(@"Error: Create folder failed %@",userPath2);`